# Android: Change edittext style

Tags: android, android-edittext

when i make an edittext in Android it looks like a white rectangular shape, how do i make it look like this one? [Example photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHAgO.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.EditText"` to your EditText input.

Comment: in which part of the xml should i put it?

Comment: `<EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.EditText" />`